# GVIM : in /root/.vimrc i have ":colorscheme desert" which worked, but where would i have found this value if someone hadn't told me?

Tags: linux, terminal, vim

So in GVIM i changed the color-scheme to

```
desert
```

but i never understood how to find this line

```
:colorscheme desert
```

so i could place it in

```
/root/.vimrc
```

file.

where would i have found out about " `:colorscheme desert` " ?

Comment: Vim has a large learning curve. I'm not sure where you would find it by yourself. You could find it by reading other peoples vimrc and taking the settings you like from them. (And at the same time reading about them in the help (`:h`) so you know what they do)

Comment: @FDinoff, so there is no way i could have found `:colorscheme desert` to insert into my `/root/.vimrc` unless some other person told me it ?

Comment: You could read the documentation its really good. (However you might be overwhelmed if you start at the top and read everything)

Answer (score 1):

You could read the help (it is quite long and very detailed)

```
:h
```

Opens up to the main help for vim. Under getting started you will see the following. You might have to scroll down a bit (Use <kbd>Control</kbd>+<kbd>f</kbd> to page down)

```
usr_toc.txt   Table Of Contents

Getting Started
usr_01.txt  About the manuals
usr_02.txt  The first steps in Vim
usr_03.txt  Moving around
usr_04.txt  Making small changes
usr_05.txt  Set your settings
usr_06.txt  Using syntax highlighting
usr_07.txt  Editing more than one file
usr_08.txt  Splitting windows
usr_09.txt  Using the GUI
usr_10.txt  Making big changes
usr_11.txt  Recovering from a crash
usr_12.txt  Clever tricks
```

It seems the that `usr_06.txt`  is related to syntax highlighting so that might be worth reading. So type `:h usr_06.txt` or `<c-]>` (<kbd>Control</kbd>+<kbd>]</kbd>) to jump to that file when your cursor is on top of it.

Once you are in there you can look at the table of contents again.

```
06.1  Switching it on
06.2  No or wrong colors?
06.3  Different colors
06.4  With colors or without colors
06.5  Printing with colors
06.6  Further reading
```

Different colors seems to be what you want. So type `:h 06.3` (or `<c-]>`) and the first paragraph talks about changing the colorscheme.

---

<kbd>Control</kbd>+<kbd>]</kbd> jumps to a tag and is talked about in `:h tagsrch.txt` (And on the line "Jump to a subject" immediately as you open `:h`)

Answer (score 0):

On Debian Linux, it's part of the the `vim-runtime` package and sits in `/usr/share/vim/vim73/colors/desert.vim`. You can list contents of this direcory for more options. I don't think they have hard-coded color schemes in vim itself, so vim help will not list them for you.

I suppose like most other vim plugins, customized color schemes can also be put in `~/.vim` directory.

Answer (score 0):

The help have an auto completion feature.

So you can type, `:help color` followed by <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>d</kbd>. You won't necessary find the good entry right of the bat but it should put you on the right track. It would have shown you a `colorscheme` option.

An alternative is to use `:helpgrep`.  `:helpgrep color` should give you a list of help file wich contains the string `color`.